# swf upload to amazon s3 subdirectory

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am successful in uploading to amazon s3 bucket using post and swf upload but can any one tell me how to upload to a subdirectory inside my bucket.

I am using php as my server side language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can upload to a sub folder using post but when i combine it with swf upload i can only upload to my bucket.

Answer (score 2):

you should include the file path in your policy and post parameters. for example, when setting your policy array, set the key of the file to be "/path/../filename.ext".

```
array("starts-with", '$key', $this->file_key);
```

use that in the key in post parameters

Answer (score 1):

For nesting files on bucket's subfolder I first created subfolder via PHP as below:

```
if(!($s3->if_object_exists($S3_BUCKET, 'mysubfolder/'))) {
     $s3->create_object($S3_BUCKET,'mysubfolder/', array('body' => ''));
};
```

then with SWFUPLOAD via javascript code in the post_params array I appended on key value the name of my nested subfolder as follows:

```
post_params: {"AWSAccessKeyId":"AXAXAXAXAX", "key":"mysubfolder/${filename}", "acl":"public-read", "policy":"SAgXQ0KCX0=","signature":"QvbfiUUsRby8wovt=","success_action_status":"201", "content-type":"image/"}
```

Another code segment. check where is uppercase letters

```
/********************************* PHP CODE */

if(!($s3->if_object_exists($S3_BUCKET, 'mysubfolder/'))) {
     $s3->create_object($S3_BUCKET,'IMAGES/', array('body' => ''));
};

....

/********************************** JAVASCRIPT CODE */

post_params: {"AWSAccessKeyId":"AXAXAXAXAX", "key":"IMAGES/${filename}", "acl":"public-read", "policy":"SAgXQ0KCX0=","signature":"QvbfiUUsRby8wovt=","success_action_status":"201", "content-type":"image/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [php-aws library](http://php-aws.googlecode.com/), there's really not much to it:

```
$S3   = new S3(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET);
$from = 'fileonyourserver.ext';
$to   = '/path/to/place/in/inside/bucket/.../file.ext';
if ($S3->putObject(AWS_BUCKET, $to, $from, true)){
   //upload success
}
```

Comment: That AWS library link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem as well, it seems amazon s3 doesn't have folder concept, the workaround most people suggest is create a object with names like folder/test.txt.

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down, it actually worked for me. I looked high and low for a way do this, and this worked perfect. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this article helpful:

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/03/upload-to-amazon-s3-with-uploadify/

It's using Uploadify instead of the SWFUpload library (but I think Uploadify uses the SWFUpload library internally). Regardless, the concept is still the same. You need to include the folder in your policy and request.